# How does fragment & ActiveRecord or SQL caching work in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching

Alright, I have a basic CMS in the works & would liked to try my hand at caching what are essentially a set of dynamically generated navigation links. In my `pages_controller`, I have the following action to toggle a page's visibility, as well as the query to create an `@nav_links` variable based on those pages that are visible

```
before_filter :nav_links, only: [:index, :new, :show, :edit]

def toggle
  @visibility = @page.visible? ? false : true
  unless @page.update_attribute(:visible, @visibility)
    flash[:alert] = "Uh oh! Looks like something went wrong."
  end
  expire_fragment "nav"
end

def nav_links
  @nav_links = {}
  groups = PageGroup.order("id")
  groups.each do |group|
    if group.visible?
      @nav_links[group.name.to_sym] = group.pages.where(visible: true)
    end
  end
end
```

In my view, I've wrapped the section of the page pertaining to `@nav_links` with `<% cache "nav" do %>...<% end %>`. So my question, what happens exactly when one of these actions is called?

1. Does Rails still execute the before_filter, query the database, & re-populate the `@nav_links` hash per visit? Or does it only get called if the view can't find a copy of `@nav_links` in the cache? If it doesn't execute each time, does Rails use SQL caching by default to use the same results unless a record was changed?
2. Do I need to modify the `nav_links` method as well or will the cache work as expected with only the changes to the view & action that updates a page's visibility?

Thanks in advanced; I'm new at Rails so I hope my questions make sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `cache "nav"` wrapped around some template code, that code will be run once, the results cached, and the cache will be reused until the *template* changes. Your `cache` invocation doesn't reference any data objects, so there is no application state that can change which would result in the cache being busted.

Also, I'm fairly certain that `expire_fragment` doesn't work with Rails 4 [cache digests.](http://railscasts.com/episodes/387-cache-digests)